How big were the armies of the Mycenaean Civilization during the Late Helladic Period and during the Late Bronze Age Collapse?
Just about how many soldiers could you expect to encounter during the Late Helladic Period and the Late Bronze Age Collapse in Mycenaean Greece? Did they have a significant number of camp followers then?

The "Collapse" part of the "Late Bronze Age Collapse" was that the Greek area slipped into illiteracy, and because of that we don't really know any details of what happened. So this info would not have been recorded. I'm not sure if this is the kind of information that could be recovered archeologically.

In general, all military numbers in antiquity should be regarded as unreliable.

Maybe ~150,000
As TED points out in a comment, this is very difficult to answer because of the lack of physical or written evidence.
However, the Iliad may provide a clue.
The Iliad was written down ~800 BC, but discusses events that supposedly occurred in Mycenaean times. The Catalog of Ships references places that were ruins at the time of composition, but have been subsequently identified by archeology, suggesting that the Iliad may have been part of an oral tradition that was passed down through the Bronze Age Collapse.
This same Catalog of Ships lists 164 settlements that provided soldiers, and states that over 1,000 ships were sent to Troy.
The Boeotian ships were said to have 120 soldiers per ship, which might imply ~140k soldiers for the whole army.
But Probably Much Less
It seems a little unlikely that 140k men sailed to Troy. 120 men per ship implies Tiryns - population 10,000 - sent 1,000 or more soldiers. A polity sending 10% of their population to war is pretty extraordinary.
Another way to approach this would be to assume the ships from the different settlements were different sizes, but that the settlements themselves were roughly similar and thus provided similar numbers of fighters. There were 29 Boeotian settlements, and they provided 50 ships of 120 men each, for roughly 200 fighters per settlement.
Multiplying that out by 164 settlements gives just shy of 34,000 fighters.
And Probably Less Than That
So we think (if we believe that the Iliad is historical, and if our math is right) that ~34,000 Greeks went to war in the Iliad.
The Iliad is quite literally the most storied war of the Mycenaean period.
We would probably expect that a "typical" conflict in this period would be smaller scale.
Other (Possibly Better) Sources
The Egyptian Pharaoh Merneptah claimed to have killed or captured 15,000 of the Sea People in a great victory circa 1,200 BC. It's difficult to know if the record is exaggerated, or how many of the enemy might have escaped even if claim is accurate.
But it seems to imply that a battle with over 10,000 fighters per side is feasible in this era.

@cmw - "It is a completely fictionalized account" [citation needed]

@cmw - I'm familiar enough with the Homeric question to include a link to the "Historicity of the Iliad" wiki article and a bunch of hedging language like "if, may, if we believe, etc" -- which is why I found your comment so rude.

I apologize for "rude" (blunt) response. I guess no criticism is necessary since you already know why this answer is nonsensical.

I seem to recall research argueing that the actual numbers are much much smaller than what is written in these sources. First, one can try to estimate what proportion of young healthy men a bronze age community can afford to  have that does not produce food and even supply with food (not many). Second of all the people they send of to war, only a (small?) proportion are actual fighters/ soldiers, the rest is needed for supply.

@quarague If they weren't still standing, 99 out of 100 historians would prove you that the pyramid of Keops wasn't more than 10m high. We 21th century humans tend to downplay by several orders of magnitude what people from old ages could actually do, unless violently smashed in the face with hard, undeniable facts. Even if the numbers in ancient sources are inflated, I don't trust at all these couch academics who pull numbers of water needs and food production out of their asses to conclude that the siege of Troy was actually carried by seven people and a dog.
